# Looking for a SF short story about a hotel frozen in time

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I read it like 7 years ago. Many scientists — I remember Einstein — are there. You can only go if you are invited. Every time someone leaves, you can see from the window of the hotel the time he/she came from.

Comment: It's not the one you're looking for but Edmond Hamilton's "The Inn Outside the World" is a classic story about a place where great men from different eras get together—Julius Caesar, Ben Franklin, a space-explorer from the 25th century. You can [read it here](https://archive.org/stream/Weird_Tales_Canadian_Ed._v38n03_1945-09#page/n77/mode/1up). Same concept as your story? Do you remember anything about the plot of your story? Did you read it in a book or magazine, or on the web?